# Need help connecting Node to Neo4j database with Kubernetes

Tags: node.js, docker, neo4j, kubernetes

Currently, I am getting the `ECONNREFUSED` where node can't connect to the database. I am not sure where the database host is supposed to end up. Should I be using `localhost:7474`, `127.0.0.1:7474`, `0.0.0.0:7474`, or am I supposed to use some host that gets generated when I get my Kubernetes pods up that I can somehow pass in? e.g. like `$(minikube ip) = 192.168.90.100:7474`, but for my database? Is there an ENV containing the database host that I am supposed to be pulling from somewhere?

```
const neo4jDatabase = connect({
  server: 'http://<what goes here!?>:7474',
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  pass: process.env.DB_PASS,
});
```

I seem to have gotten the pods running with the below .yml configs, but am not sure if the neo4j one is correct.

```
NAME                     READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
neo4j-4166717986-8qbwq   1/1       Running   0          41m
node-481322091-g27md     1/1       Running   0          11m
```

**node.yml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: node
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: node
        tier: backend
        track: stable
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: node
          image: "myapp"
          ports:
            - name: nodeport
              containerPort: 8080
          env:
           - name: DB_USER
             valueFrom:
               configMapKeyRef:
                 name: config
                 key: db_user
           - name: DB_PASS
             valueFrom:
               configMapKeyRef:
                 name: config
                 key: db_pass
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: node
spec:
  selector:
    app: node
    tier: backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort:
  type: LoadBalancer
```

**neo4j.yml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: neo4j
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: neo4j
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: neo4j
          image: "my-neo4j"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 7474
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: neo4j
  labels:
    run: neo4j
spec:
  selector:
    run: neo4j
  ports:
    - port: 7474
      targetPort: 7474
      protocol: TCP
```

Comment: I think you have to open port 7687 public, so that your node driver can connect to neo4j, if you are using the official one... check also https://github.com/mneedham/neo4j-kubernetes

Comment: Woah, I only have 1 .yaml file for Neo4j, but that GitHub project has a ton. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a less known feature of Kubernetes is the fact that some *magic* environment variables are injected in the running pods.

In your particular case, pods have an environment variable for each service in the namespace. The format is the following:

```
<your service>_SERVICE_HOST
<your service name>_SERVICE_PORT_EXPOSED_PORT
```

You can verify this is true by attaching to a running pod with `kubectl exec -ti <your pod id> sh` and issuing a `printenv` command.

Please note that if the service was created AFTER the pod, you have to delete the pod with `kubectl delete pod <your pod id>` to force recreation (and injection) of the environment variables.

In your case, the final code will look like this:

```
const serviceHost = process.ENV.NEO4J_SERVICE_HOST;
const servicePort = process.ENV.NEO4J_SERVICE_PORT_EXPOSED_PORT;
const neo4jDatabase = connect({
  server: `http://${serviceHost}:${servicePort}`,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  pass: process.env.DB_PASS,
});
```